# How to fix count down problem Java using counter

Tags: java, counter

I'm trying to create a code that uses a counter to countdown from int n.
I'm able to count up just fine, but when I execute the code, it does not countdown at all.
Does anybody know whereabouts I went wrong?

```
public void countUp(int n) {
        System.out.println("*** Counting up " + n);
        for (int step = 1; step <= n; step++) {
            System.out.println("counter = " + currentCount);
            currentCount += 1;
        }
    }
    public void countDown(int n){
        System.out.println("*** Counting down " + n);
        for (int step = 1; step >= n; step--){
            System.out.println("counter = " +currentCount);
            currentCount -= 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well `step >= n` is immediately false for any `n` greater than 1.

Comment: When you count down. You want to initialize step to n and stop when you get to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void countDown(int n){
    for (int step = n; step >= 0; step--){
        System.out.println("counter = " + step );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `countDown()` function is not running at all because of the condition `step>=n` the condition is never satisfied unless `n==1`.

I don't know what value is exactly present in the variable `currentCount` considering it is `n` so just change the loop parameter to the following:-

```
for (int step = n; step >= i; step--)
```

Hope this help.